# Confused about a Lipschitz problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is Lipschitz of order 1 at $x$, is it differentiable at $x$?

A function $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\beta$ at $x$ if there is a constant D such that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le D \,|x-y|^\beta$$

for all $y$ in the interval containing $x$.

If yes, can anyone motivate a proof for me?

Comment: what does it mean Lipschitz of order 1? What is the order of a Lipschitz function?

Comment: That is typically called [Holder continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holder_continuous), but we get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, no (as $f(x)=\vert x\vert$ demonstrates).  However, you should take a look at [Rademacher's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem), which says that Lipschitz functions are almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: I was think of a $f(x) = |x|$, but couldn't quite flesh the entire thing out. Don't know why this condition is giving me such an issue. It has been very hard to gather intuition. Thanks for the theorem. I will take a look at it. Would there be a way you can walk me through that counter example?

Comment: Which part?  The function is Lipschitz via [reverse triangle inquality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality), and clearly not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Darn it! The reverse triangle inequality, my arch nemesis! LOL. Thanks for pointing that out. My friend wrote that, but he told me it's a formula, but could not name it and I had sat down to prove it wrong =)

Comment: one quick question, is the converse of the statement true?

Comment: Only locally, i.e. $f(x)$ continuously differentiable implies $f$ is Lipschitz on every compact subset of its domain.  $f(x)=x^2$ is smooth but not globally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) = |x|$.